# Android change value of method to check against button ID

Tags: java, android, regex, reflection

I am trying to make a method to iterate over a set of buttons and up the count of they meet the correct condition.
In doing so I want to know if it is possible to increment the value of methods such as `R.id.gridButton` method based on the value of the counter using regex or if that is not possible, would reflection would be the correct way to go about it.

Example: 
`i == 1`
`R.id.gridButton1`

`i == 2`
`R.id.gridButton2`

```
public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        System.out.println("Table child count: " + tableLayout.getChildCount());

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Value of i: " + i);
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getId() == R.id.gridButton1 ) {
                        buttonCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Child count: " + buttonCount);
        return buttonCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean a

```
switch(view.getId())
{
    case R.id.gridButton1:
        //do whatever you need to
        break;
    case R.id.gridButton2:
        //...
       break;

    default:
       break;
}
```

that seems to be the easiest, most elegant approach to the idea you're after.

Comment: Yeah that would be great for a small amount of buttons. But to scale it up would start to get messy. I'm thinking somehow to be able to adapt to greater and greater numbers of buttons. Say a grid with 100 or 200 buttons

Comment: If you need a "grid of 100 or 200 buttons" perhaps you need to revisit your original idea. OR - have a giant, messy, `switch()` piece of code in there somewhere... which will give hell to the next-maintenance-person-to-work-with-that-code.